# Show that n>0 has an inverse modulo φ>1 iff gcd(n,φ)=1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can you please show me how to show that $n > 0$ has an inverse modulo $\phi >1$  if and only if $gcd(n,\phi)=1$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's basically a rephrasing of the Euclidean Lemma.  $n*a \equiv 1 \mod \phi \iff n*a = 1 + k*\phi$ for some $k$, $\iff  n*a - k*\phi = 1 \iff \gcd(n, \phi) = 1$.  Can you do that?  Hint.   $\gcd(n,\phi)|n; \gcd(n,\phi)|\phi$ so $\gcd(n,\phi)|n*a -k*\phi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is equivalent to the statement that if $(a,b)=1$ then there exist integers $x,y$ such that $ax+by=1$ because you can just take it mod b to obtain $ax\equiv 1 \pmod{b}$ but this is just the Bezout identity when a,b are coprime.

I like this approach because it gives you a hint of how to calculate the inverse modulo b, for example suppose you want to find $31x\equiv 1 \pmod{427}$ then you can just run the Euclidean algorithm:
$$(31,427)=(31,24)=(7,24)=(7,3)=(1,3)=1$$

Now keeping track of the multiples of 31 and 427:

$$ \begin{align*} (31,427)&=(31,427-13\cdot31) \\&=(31-(427-13\cdot31),
427-13\cdot31) \\&=(14\cdot31-427,427-13\cdot31) \\&=(14\cdot31-427,427-13\cdot31-3(14\cdot31-427)) \\&=(14\cdot31-427,4\cdot427-55\cdot31) \\&=(14\cdot31-427-2(4\cdot427-55\cdot31),4\cdot427-55\cdot31) \\&=(124\cdot31-9\cdot427,4\cdot427-55\cdot31) \end{align*} $$

Which gives us that $124\cdot31-9\cdot427=1$ so the multiplicative inverse of 31 modulo 427 is 124. Doing the same by naively evaluating $31x\pmod{427}$ for 1,2... would have taken much longer.

Comment: See more about [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout's_identity) on Wikipedia. I strongly prefer calling it Bezout's *lemma* myself. It is clearly not an identity, after all. But unfortunately, the name has stuck.